# How can I make a short answer response into a question?

Tags: google-forms

I want to survey some beliefs of people. I am asking them to enter some beliefs, and then rate the percent at which they believe it.

Later in the form, I plan to test how much they believe these beliefs after an experiment. I also plan to have them select things (checkboxes) that relate to their belief.

The issue is that I can't predefine what they will put in the short answer, but I need a way to refer to their previous answers and ask specific questions about them.

How can I do this?

Example:

> - What did you learn this year?
>     -- "I learned X, y, z."
> - What else?
>     -- "I also learned a, b and c."
> - How much do you believe x, y, and z?"
>     -- "5/10"
> - what about a, b, and c?
>     -- "7/10"

Later in the survey:

> Here are possible truths relating to a, b, and c. select the correct ones:
>   "d, f, g"

Comment: Hi Alice, and welcome to Web Applications! I added some formatting to your text to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way to refer to their previous answers and ask specific questions about them.

Google Forms doesn't include a way to refer to previous answers. You could ask for a Software Recommendation on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.